# cursor and with_cursor() in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am fetching records from gae model using cursor() and with_cursor() logic as used in paging. but i am not sure how to check that there is no any other record in db that is pointed by cursor. i am fetching these records in chunks within some iterations.when i got my required results in the first iteration then in next iteration I want to check there is no any record in model but I not get any empty/None value of cursor at this stage.please let me know how to perform this check with cursors in google app engine with python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your model is extending ndb, you should use fetch_page().  If it's not extending ndb, you may want to consider changing.  It's not completely backwards compatible but the data does not have to be migrated.

```
from google.appengine.ext.ndb import model

class User(model.Model):
   name = model.StringProperty()

users, cursor, more = User.query(User.name == "Jon").fetch_page(25)

if more: 
    # Do next page logic
    next_users = User.query(User.name == "Jon").fetch_page(25, start_cursor=cursor)
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not 100% sure about that but what i used to do is compare the last cursor with the actual cursor and i think i noticed that they were the same so i came to the conclusion that it was the last cursor.

Comment: ok , i got your point. but is there any other proper solution ?

Comment: don't think there is an official way to check if there could be another batch after the last one you fetched.

Answer (score -1):

If you count your query results and the number is equal to the fetch, you have more results to fetch. If the number of results is less, than you have fetched all query results.

To demonstrate the idea : I use this function to transfer data between App Engine and a Google Apps spreadsheet. The transfer is done in pages; This function tries yo optimize the page size. 
args['Cursor'] hold the cursor. The first time args['cursor'] = None. args['Page'] holds the page size.
The query can be something like : query = aLotofData.all()

```
def makePage(args, proces, query):

    if args['Cursor'] != 'NONE' : query.with_cursor(args['Cursor'])  # next page with cursor

    page = []                                                   # transfer the selected entities in pages
    lines = 0                                                   # lines per page counter
    fetch = int(args['Page'])                                   # fetch can vary; because we optimize the page transfer 
    while lines < 0.8 * int(args['Page']) :                     # optimize pagination when page less than 80% filled
        count = 0                                               # number of entities processed per fetch
        for entity in query.fetch(fetch) :
            count += 1
            page_line = proces(entity)
            if page_line :           
                page.append(page_line)                          # variable function call to preces the entity
                lines += 1
        if count < fetch :                                      # no more entities ?
            cursor = 'NONE'                                     # last page, no cursor 
            break
        cursor = query.cursor()                                 # save current cursor fot he next run                
        query.with_cursor(cursor)                               # set the cursor for the fetch iteration (optimize)
        fetch = int(args['Page']) - lines                       # and fetch the number of page lines left to fill

    logging.debug('Transfered : %d next_cursor : %s' %(lines, cursor)) 

    return simplejson.dumps({'cursor' : cursor, 'page' : page})
```

The function "proces" processes each entity. When proces returns None, the line is not appended to the current page.

Comment: "If you count your query results and the number is equal to the fetch, you have more results to fetch" this is a pretty lazy check because what if you page by 50 and you have 200 entities? the last fetch will be 50 and you think you have another page but there isn't.

Comment: What dou you think is the change that your last cursor query will result in exactly the page size? By the way, this change becomes bigger if you have to use a small page zize. And if you think there is a big change, then choose another (smart / optimized) page size.

Comment: sorry but i don't understand what you mean by change... what are you trying to say?

Comment: Sorry for my English. I meant CHANCE. And to give you  an example:

    query = AlotOfData.all()
    for each in query.fetch(5000)

You receive a number of results. But if this is the last cursor query, the number of results is between 0 and 5000. THE CHANCE is very small that this number is exactly 5000. When the result is exactly 5000 you have to do another query, giving you zero results.

Comment: thats what im saying. there **is** a chance that the number of fetched results in the last query is the full number and that is not good enough to make pagination work like it should. obviously you don't care about that and you are fine but it still gives you a margin of error which and i wouldn't be happy with it.

Comment: It is not an error. It is a look ahead optimization solution.
I do not understand your problem. The chance that you query and receive ZERO results on the last cursor query is equal to the chance that you receive one result. Both results tell you, that you have fetched all the query results.

Comment: And to give you another solution for this problem. After you have fetched the results and you have received a full page, you save the new cursor and than fetch another (1) row. If that fails, you know your the query is finished. IF not you continue with the saved cursor. So, look ahead one result.

Comment: you don't need to give me a solution. what you do in this case is have a few datastore reads more and you spend more time instead of optimizing your pagination for speed and cost. what if the next cursor at the last query would return the same exact cursor and you could compare these 2 to know if there is another page or not?! why wouldn't you do that and instead choose to fetch another entity?

Comment: To get the next cursor you have to fetch data. The cursor is bound to a result. Do you understand cursors, Here is some background : http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlqueryclass.html#GqlQuery_cursor

Comment: lets stop this. you obviously don't get what im writing.